# Text box with automated coordinate reference system in use on Qgis

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, print-composer, expression

Using an expression, is it possible to automatically fill a text box placed on the map (in the composer) showing the reference coordinate system of the project? If possible, how would that expression be like?